# AutoFixture returning nulls for all values on a Moq'ed interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofixture

I'm using AutoFixture to populate a fairly huge interface object, but I'm getting a null (or default value) for every property. I've tried both:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var input = fixture.Create<Mock<ICustomer>>();
```

And:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Register(() => Mock.Of<ICustomer>());
var input = fixture.Create<ICustomer>();
```

In both cases, none of the properties on the resulting `ICustomer` are populated. I'm guessing I've missed something obvious?

Comment: You register new instance of mocked `ICustomer`. So you didn't use benefits of AutoFixture which generate "dummy" values. For mocked instance you still need provide some default values

Comment: To those who itch to close this question as a duplicate: reconsider. It's hardly a duplicate, as the accepted answer implies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [AutoFixture.AutoMoq](http://nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoMoq) package for this:

```
[Fact]
public void HowToCreateAnAutoConfiguredMoq()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization());
    var c = fixture.Create<ICustomer>();
    Assert.NotEqual(default(string), c.Name);
}
```

Personally, I'm not a big fan of `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization`, because I think it makes the tests too implicit. I believe that [explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020), so I normally prefer instead using `AutoMoqCustomization` instead, and combine that with explicitly configuring those behaviours that matter for the test in question.

See also [How to configure AutoMoq to set up all properties](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/05/how-to-configure-automoq-to-set-up-all-properties).

Comment: Lovely! Thanks!

I agree on the implicit nature of this stuff, but I'm dealing with over 100 properties so its at the point of 'unmanageable'

Comment: Thanks for explicitly mention of value of explicit test configuration